# Magento override extensions template

Tags: magento

I need to override a file in one of my extensions. I don't want to modify the file directly, I would prefer to override it with a local file.

The original file is located at

```
app/design/frontend/aw_mobile/iphone/template/page/1column.phtml
```

My themes folder is located at

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE-NAME/default
```

I tried putting the new file at

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE-NAME/aw_mobile/iphone/template/page/1column.phtml
```

But that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thanks I could really use the help!

Comment: Small correction to your terminology that might help you solve the problem on your own.  The convention is app/design/frontend/[package-name]/[theme-name]/template/etc.  You can't (to my knowledge) share templates across design packages.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I was just reading your blog trying to figure out how to solve this! I corrected my post. So if I cant share the template as I suggested, do I need to create a module to override the template? If so I am confused how I would make that module, or is it not possible?

Comment: It sounds like your extension is already setting a custom theme name.  **They're** using a template override to implement functionality, which means you don't get to. I'd look into using `local.xml` to set the template on a per page basis, or a module with a class rewrite for `page/html` that detects settings 1column.phtml, and uses your template instead.  Might be worth contacting the extension vendor as well — they may have a suggestion or solution.

Comment: Couldn't you just put it here:  `app/design/frontend/PACKAGE-NAME/iphone/template/page/1column.phtml`?